# Intellij puts 2 tab spaces after code block opening brace brace despite use spaces instead of tabs and 4 spaces as the indent

Tags: intellij-idea

As seen in [image: Indentation settings]

it should use spaces instead of tabs, and the indentation should be 4 spaces. However when I type a function declaration and a curly brace and hit Enter, it puts 2 tabs totalling 8 space width. I'm having to manually shift + tab after writing my code to reset the wrong formatting. Why does it not honour the settings? I don't think I have any third party code formatter installed.

Comment: A similar problem was fixed in the 2023.2 build. Please try using the latest version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion If the problem remains contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new for further assistance

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question. Go to Settigns -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java. In the "Tabs and Indents" tab, there should be a field called "Continuation indent". Change this accordingly.

Mine was originally 8 and I was using 4 spaces as the tab size. Changed to 4 and it works!